# android sqlite query search error

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listview, android-fragments, android-sqlite

I have been stuck on this one for the past couple of hours (sadly).

I am building an application with SQLite where the application can do all the flexible SQL commands. I am currently stuck on how to search the query from columns other than the ID.

SQLiteDb:

```
public class SqliteDbTab extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
  {
public static String DATABASENAME = "androidadvancesqlite";
public static String TABTABLE = "TABTABLE";

public static String ID = "ID";
public static String NAME = "name";
public static String PHONE = "PhOnE";
public static String MAIL = "mail";
public static String ADDRESS = "address";
public static String IMAGE = "image";

private ArrayList<Helperdb> cartList = new ArrayList<Helperdb>();
Context c;

public SqliteDbTab(Context context)
{
    super(context, DATABASENAME, null, 33);
    c = context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE if not exists TABTABLE(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + NAME+ " text, " 
            + IMAGE + " BLOB , " 
            + PHONE + " text , "
            + MAIL + " text , "
            + ADDRESS + " TEXT)");
}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int arg1, int arg2) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABTABLE);
    onCreate(db);
}

public void addContact(Helperdb productitem) 
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("NAME", productitem.name);
    contentValues.put("PHONE", productitem.phone);
    contentValues.put("MAIL", productitem.mail);
    contentValues.put("ADDRESS", productitem.address);
    contentValues.put("IMAGE", productitem.image);
    db.insert(TABTABLE, null, contentValues);
    db.close();
}

// update
public void updateContact(Helperdb productList)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("NAME", productList.name);
    contentValues.put("PHONE", productList.phone);
    contentValues.put("MAIL", productList.mail);
    contentValues.put("ADDRESS", productList.address);
    contentValues.put("IMAGE", productList.image);
    db.update(TABTABLE, contentValues, "ID="+ productList.id, null);
    db.close(); 
}

public void emptyProduct() 
{
    try {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL(TABTABLE);
        db.close();
        } catch (Exception e) 
        {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
}

public void removeProduct(String id,String name, String phone, String mail,String address,byte[] blob)
{
    try {
        String[] args = { id };
        getWritableDatabase().delete(TABTABLE, "ID=?", args);
    } catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public ArrayList<Helperdb> getProudcts() 
{
    cartList.clear();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from TABTABLE", null);
    if (cursor.getCount() != 0) 
    {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) 
        {
            do 
            {
                Helperdb item = new Helperdb();
                item.id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ID"));
                item.name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));                    
                item.phone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PhOnE"));
                item.mail = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("mail"));                    
                item.address = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("address"));                  
                item.image = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex("image"));

                cartList.add(item);
            }
            while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return cartList;

}

public ArrayList<Helperdb> getProudcts(String record) 
{
    cartList.clear();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor=db.query(true,TABTABLE,new String[]{"ID","name","PhOnE","mail","address","image"},"name"+"=?",new String[]{record},null,null,null,null);
    if (cursor.getCount() != 0)
    {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do {
                Helperdb item = new Helperdb();
                item.id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ID"));
                item.name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
                item.phone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PhOnE"));
                item.mail = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("mail"));                    
                item.address = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("address"));                  
                item.image = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex("image"));
                cartList.add(item);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return cartList;
}   
 }
```

java file:

```
package com.example.simpletablist;
public class Tab3 extends Activity implements TextWatcher 
{
EditText _searchbox;
private ProgressBar showprogress;
searchtask dotask;
private ArrayList<Helperdb> _productList;
ListView _listview;
SqliteDbTab db;
public AutoCompleteTextView myAutoComplete;
private ArrayList<Helperdb> _productList_Temp;
String query = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activitytab3);
    _searchbox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtsearchproduct);
    showprogress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.showprogress);
    _listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.searchlistview);
    _searchbox.addTextChangedListener(textwatcher);
}

Runnable runn = new Runnable()
{   
    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        handlersearch.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    }
};
TextWatcher textwatcher = new TextWatcher() 
{
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,int count)
    {
        Log.i("---onTextChanged ----", "---------onTextChanged ----");
        if (_searchbox.getText().toString().length() > 2) 
        {
            query = _searchbox.getText().toString().replace(" ", "%20");
            handlersearch.removeCallbacks(runn);
            handlersearch.post(runn);
        } else
        {
            showprogress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if (dotask != null)
            {
                if (dotask.getStatus().equals(AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING))
                {
                    dotask.cancel(true);
                }
            }

            handlersearch.removeCallbacks(runn);
            _productList = new ArrayList<Helperdb>();
            _productList.clear();
            _listview.setAdapter(new CustomBaseAdapter(Tab3.this,_productList));
        }
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
};

Handler handlersearch = new Handler() 
{
    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) 
    {
        dotask = new searchtask();
        dotask.execute();
    };
};

private class searchtask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> 
{
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        showprogress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    };

    protected void onPostExecute(Void param)
    {
        // animation.dismiss();
        showprogress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (_productList == null)
        return;
        ArrayList<String> item = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < _productList.size(); i++) 
        {
            item.add(_productList.get(i).name);
        }

        myAutoComplete = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.myautocomplete);

        myAutoComplete.addTextChangedListener(Tab3.this);

        myAutoComplete.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Tab3.this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, item));

        _productList_Temp = new ArrayList<Helperdb>();
        for (int i = 0; i < _productList.size(); i++) 
        {
            _productList_Temp.add(_productList.get(i));
        }
        _listview.setAdapter(new CustomBaseAdapter(Tab3.this,_productList_Temp));
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
    {
        db = new SqliteDbTab(getApplicationContext());
        db.getWritableDatabase();
        ArrayList<Helperdb> product_list = db.getProudcts(query);

        for (int i = 0; i < product_list.size(); i++) 
        {
            String tidno = product_list.get(i).getid();
            System.out.println("tidno>>>>>" + tidno);
            String tname = product_list.get(i).getName();
            String tphone = product_list.get(i).getPhone();
            Helperdb _ProductModel = new Helperdb();
            _ProductModel.setid(tidno);
            _ProductModel.setName(tname);
            _ProductModel.setPhone(tphone);
            _productList.add(_ProductModel);
        }
    //   _productList = _parser.getProductList();
        return null;
    }
}

private class CustomBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
{
    LayoutInflater _inflater;
    List<Helperdb> productList;

    public CustomBaseAdapter(Context context, List<Helperdb> productList) 
    {
        _inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.productList = productList;
    }

    public int getCount() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return productList.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        ViewHolder _holder;
        if (convertView == null) 
        {               
            convertView = _inflater.inflate(R.layout.contactlist, null);
            _holder = new ViewHolder();
            _holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_title_text);
            _holder.phone = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_price);
        convertView.setTag(_holder);
        } else 
        {
            _holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        _holder.name.setText(productList.get(position).name.trim());
        _holder.phone.setText(productList.get(position).phone);
        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView name;
        TextView phone;
    }
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
  }
```

logcat file:

```
 12-13 10:47:50.269: I/---onTextChanged ----(2307): ---------onTextChanged ----
 12-13 10:47:50.489: I/---onTextChanged ----(2307): ---------onTextChanged ----
 12-13 10:47:50.729: I/---onTextChanged ----(2307): ---------onTextChanged ----
   12-13 10:47:51.569: I/---onTextChanged ----(2307): ---------onTextChanged ----
  12-13 10:47:51.769: I/---onTextChanged ----(2307): ---------onTextChanged ----
  12-13 10:47:51.909: I/---onTextChanged ----(2307): ---------onTextChanged ----
    12-13 10:47:52.649: I/---onTextChanged ----(2307): ---------onTextChanged ----
  12-13 10:47:53.749: I/---onTextChanged ----(2307): ---------onTextChanged ----
    12-13 10:47:53.808: I/---onTextChanged ----(2307): ---------onTextChanged ----
  12-13 10:47:55.478: I/---onTextChanged ----(2307): ---------onTextChanged ----
    12-13 10:47:55.598: I/System.out(2307): tidno>>>>>5
```

please help me:i am doing search retrieving full name..not getting at i entered first letter only...

![Search UI]

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: have you got some errors?? if yes, please post logcat.

Comment: no errors doing search when i entered full name then its searching ..it does not taking first alphabet..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try "name"+"='"+record+"%'"
you can try a query like this

```
String SEARCH_QUERY = "SELECT * FROM TABTABLE WHERE name like '"+record+"%'";

Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(SEARCH_QUERY, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
if (cursor.getCount() > 0)
{
  do {
                Helperdb item = new Helperdb();
                item.id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ID"));
                item.name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
                item.phone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PhOnE"));
                item.mail = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("mail"));                    
                item.address = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("address"));                  
                item.image = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex("image"));
                cartList.add(item);
     } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
cursor.close();
```

Comment: can you please explain with an example because it is working at my side if I pass "a" in string then it shows all the words starting with "a",

Comment: @ Vaibhav Agarwal ...k .can i send my full code ...give me ur mail address

Comment: @ Vaibhav Agarwal Thank u ..i get it//